# Archimedean property written multiplicatively

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $(\Gamma,+,\leq)$ be an ordered abelian group. We know that archimedean property can be stated as: for all $a,b\in\Gamma$ with $a>0,b\geq0$, there exists $n\geq0$ such that $b\leq na$. However, if we consider the multiplicative case, namely $(\Gamma,\cdot,\leq)$ is the ordered abelian group. Is there exists Archimedean property written multiplicatively? I think there is. And I state that as follows: for all $a,b\in\Gamma$ with $b<1,a\leq1$, there exists $n\geq0$ such that $b^{n}\leq a$. Is it correct?

In fact, I failed to show that it is equivalent to $\Gamma$ having convex rank 1.

Comment: Direct proof:
Assume a>0 , b>=0 then  there is n>=0 such that b<=na

A. 1/b > 1/ na and it's important to note that b,a,n can't be 0. Try to define them as |b1|<1, |a1|<=1, 

B. b1 > a1n  we have 3 cases  n=0, n>1, n <1
      Case 1 
       (b1)^0=1>a1 given
       Case 2
       (b1....b1) = b1^n>(b1^n-1)a1 n 
 
      Case 3 
        b1^n  >( b1^n-1) a1n=1/( b1)^1-n * a1 n 

I would not conclude your conjecture though.

Comment: I think I can help. But first can you clarify what "convex rank" is?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Let $(\Gamma,\cdot,\leq)$ be an ordered abelian group. The *convex rank* of $\Gamma$ is the supremum of the length over chains of convex subgroups of $\Gamma$. A *convex subgroup* $H$ of $\Gamma$ is a subgroup such that for $x\in\Gamma,x'\in H$ with $1\geq x\geq x'$, we have $x\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly stated the multiplicative version of the Archimedean property.

Let $\Gamma$ be an ordered multiplicative group with the Archimedean property.

Suppose $H$ is a convex subgroup of $\Gamma$ with  $H\ne \{1\}$. Let $1\ne x\in H.$ Then $\{x,x^{-1}\}\subset H$ and one member of $\{x,x^{-1}\}$ is $>1.$
So WLOG let $1<x\in H.$

(i). If $1\le y\in\Gamma$ there exists $n\in \Bbb N_0$ with $y\le x^n\in H .$ But $H$ is convex with $\{1,x^n\}\subset H$ and $1\le y\le x^n$ so $y\in H$.

(ii). If $1>z\in \Gamma$ then $1<z^{-1}$ so $z^{-1}\in H$ by (i), so $z\in H.$

So $H=\Gamma.$

So the only convex subgroups of $\Gamma$ are $\Gamma$ and $\{1\}.$

Appendix. It was unnecessary to assume $\Gamma$ is Abelian. Non-Abelian ordered groups do exist. But by elementary (but not brief) methods we can show that if $\Gamma$ is an ordered group with the Archimedean property then there is an ordered-group-isomorphism from $\Gamma$ to a subgroup of the additive Reals, implying $\Gamma$ is Abelian.